# Treating & as normal character with $_GET

Tags: php

I have an application that posts content to a MySQL DB via PHP. The PHP uses $_GET to pull the content from the URL and then inserts it into the DB.

This works great, but I have discovered an issue. If the user enters certain characters (", &, and others), the $_GET method does not properly separate the content from the URL.

Let's say the user posts this content:
I love blue & green

In this situation, the & symbol cuts the string after the word blue.

Is there any way for me to edit my PHP file to ignore the & symbol and to actually treat it as part of the variable it is supposed to $_GET? Any help would be great!

Comment: Fixing the damage after it's done is an ugly and unreliable workaround. Can't you just generate a valid URL?

Comment: would be nice, but the post is in a mobile application in the app store... thus i need to find a quick fix until my next iOS update... I could do an emergency update, but would rather patch for right now.

Comment: You can use a regexp in PHP to do that, in emergency.

Comment: thanks @AlexKevler, I will give it a shot and will update my question if I run into any problems! An emergency patch is all I need at the moment, but i need it fast :)

Comment: @user2492064 ((&[a-zA-Z0-9]+)=([a-zA-Z0-9]+&))+ : it's a start, but it's not guaranteed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

from http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: thanks, it looks like this might be the only solution that will not require an update to my iOS application - I will try messing with it and will let you know how it goes..

Answer (score 6):

You can URLencode data before sending it to the PHP. It's a better solution.
Specials chars must not be used in a query string if those chars are in data.

In Javascript, you can use the `escape` function : `escape(&ee)` will give `%26ee`

Answer (score 2):

The correct method is to urlencode the "&" caracter by the client : pass "%26" instead of "&"

Answer (score 1):

You could send the request as a base64 encoded string:

```
$string = base64_encode("This is my long string with &ampersands and 'quotes'");
print base64_decode($string);
```

Note that base64-encoded data takes about 33% more space than the original data.

From the manual: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

You also have [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Answer (score 1):

try to urlencode your string:

```
&
```

becomes

```
%26
```

it's a PHP function :
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 1):

What about, before creating Query string, encode it ?

```
$str = "I love blue & green ?=&˙Đ[]";
$str = urlencode($str);
echo $str;
```

Will return:

```
I%20love%20blue%20%26%20green%20%3F%3D%26%CB%99%C4%90%5B%5D
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to [URL encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding) the string before you pass it as a GET parameter. In this particular case you have to replace **&** symbol with **%26**.

This can be done for example using javascript right before you send the form.